# how to remove stagetext from frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to use stagetext in my AIR apps. I've found how to use this stagetext on  [this link](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449318635/4dot-mobile-advantage-stagetext-and-stagevideo/id2654022#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzMTg2MzUlMkZpZDI2NTQzNjImcXVlcnk9)
my question is, how to remove the stagetext when we leave a frame? I'm planning to use another stagetext in ither frame. 
I add the stagetext using script on the frame, by using addChild, 
I have tried to use removeChild, but it doesn't work..
when I enter other frame, the stagetext remain on the stage..

Answer (score 1):

Like many of the other "stage" features (StageVideo, StageWebView, Stage3D) these things sit on top of or behind the Flash display list. So you cannot use `addChild()` or `removeChild()` with StageText. In the example you linked to they don't use `addChild()` to add StageText to the screen, they use `addChild()` to add some graphics to serve as a background for the text.

I haven't worked w/StageText that much, based on the documentation you have several options:

- If you're going to get rid of it and not re-use it, just set the `stage` property of the `StageText` to null. You might also consider calling the `dispose()` method to potentially make garbage collection happen sooner.
- If you'd like to hide it temporarily, you can try setting the dimensions of the StageText's `viewPort` property so that its width/height are 0, or you can set the `visible` property to false.

All of this information is found in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html).